# Why is WPF generating a File MainWindow.g.i.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I think, when I create an application using XAML and WPF, the XAML would be compiled to BAML, embedded as a Resource and Loaded at runtime.

I have now created a small class MainWindow.cs with a Button.

Now, I see in obj\Debug the File MainWindow.g.i.cs which contains a Property for the Button etc.

I ask me now, what is the reason, that there will be a MainWindow.g.i.cs created which contains the from XAML generated Code. What is the compiler doing with this File?

Thanks for Clarification.

Comment: There is *code* in the file, which has to be compiled into your application's assembly. When you say "contains a property for the Button", you certainly mean the field generated as result of setting `x:Name` on the Button. That field has to be generated into a partial class declaration of MainWindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At compile time MsBuild/Visual Studio creates such a file for each XAML file with a build action of `Page`. This is an auto-generated partial class that takes care of the wiring up between the code in the code-behind file and the markup in the XAML file.

The `InitializeComponent()` method that is called in the constructor of the code-behind class as well as all backing fields for any controls with an `x:Name` that are defined in the XAML markup are for example defined in this class. You shouldn't need to worry nor care about these files.

Answer (score -1):

Yes , You are Right its compiled but this happens in Run Time not within compiling time .

Comment: They're compiled at compile time.